# Mongo cannot connect to localhost on OSX High Sierra 10.13.3

Tags: mongodb, macos, localhost, macos-high-sierra

This is for a Rails 5 app with Mongoid.

Apparently the mongoid.yml is OK. It works on other systems (such as OSX 10.11.6).

```
test:
  clients:
    default:
      database: interview_test
      hosts:
       - localhost:27017
```

When my app tries to connect, I get:

```
Mongo::Error::NoServerAvailable:
   No server is available matching preference: #<Mongo::ServerSelector::Primary:0x70244985573080 tag_sets=[] max_staleness=nil> using server_selection_timeout=30 and local_threshold=0.015
```

After much searching I found the following mongoid.yml ***does work***:

```
     hosts:
      - 127.0.0.1:27017
```

Here is /etc/hosts:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

Why doesn't `localhost` work on High Sierra? How to fix?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: Using `- 127.0.0.1:27017` in the config does work.